# Cómo activar botón "enviar" cuando la suma "Total" tiene cumplir la condición de que tiene que ser "mayor qué" 50 (por ejemplo)

Tags: validación, checkbox, sum

por favor si me pueden ayudar con esto: necesito que el botón de enviar esté desactivado hasta que cumpla la condición de que "total" sea igual o mayor a 50. En mi código, el "total" se forma al marcar los checkboxs de cada producto.

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y tengo algunos problemas, aún no detecto el error, puede ser en la suma de los valores de checkbox,  que están enlazados a un código java, pero creo que lo más probable es que sea en aplicar la condicional.

Ayuda por favor, aquí les dejo el código.

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click keyup', '.mis-checkboxes,.mis-adicionales', function() {
    calcular();
  });

});

function calcular() {
  var tot = $('#total');
  tot.val(0);
  $('.mis-checkboxes,.mis-adicionales').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('mis-checkboxes')) {
      tot.val(($(this).is(':checked') ? parseFloat($(this).attr('tu-attr-precio')) : 0) + parseFloat(tot.val()));
    } else {
      tot.val(parseFloat(tot.val()) + (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseFloat($(this).val())));
    }
  });
  var totalParts = parseFloat(tot.val()).toFixed(2).split('.');
  tot.val('$' + totalParts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + '.' + (totalParts.length > 1 ? totalParts[1] : '00'));
}
if (true) {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<html>

 <head>

  <td>Productos: </td>
  <br>
  <br>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <table width="500" border="2">
    <ul>
      <tr>

        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" tu-attr-precio="35" id="Café" class="mis-checkboxes" name="checkbox[]" value="Café">
          <label for="Café">Café</label>
          <br></td>
        <td>35</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>


          <input type="checkbox" tu-attr-precio="29" id="Té" class="mis-checkboxes" name="checkbox[]" value="Te">
          <label for="Té">Té</label>
          <br></td>

        <td>29</td>
      </tr>



      <td>


        <input type="checkbox" tu-attr-precio="28" id="chocolate" class="mis-checkboxes" name="checkbox[]" value="chocolate">
        <label for="chocolate">chocolate</label>
        <br></td>

      <td>28</td>
      </tr>


      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" tu-attr-precio="10" id="choclo" class="mis-checkboxes" name="checkbox[]" value="choclo">

        <label for="choclo">choclo</label>

        <br></td>

      <td>10</td>


      <table>

      </table>
      <br>
      <label><strong>Total</strong><label>
<input type="text" id="total" placeholder="0.00"required>
  <script>
                          
          if (total.value <= 50) {
            console.log("Se muestra")
            enviar.removeAttribute('disabled')
          } else {
            enviar.setAttribute('disabled', "true");
          }
    
</script>

<input type="submit"  id="enviar" value="Enviar" disabled>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente lo has enfocado bien. Simplemente tienes algunos pequeños fallos:

- Si puedes agrupa todo tu código js en un único sitio. Te será mucho más cómodo trabajar así. En tu caso, he puesto todo el js en el mismo sitio, pues no hay razón para que tengas una etiqueta script con el evento por un lado y el código js con la lógica por otro lado.
- El evento que has puesto lo he "sustituido" por lo siguiente:

1. Ejecutar tu función *calcular()*
2. Obtener el total. Simplemente quitamos el símbolo del dolar y lo pasamos a un float/int (según te interese).
3. Cambiamos los métodos *attr*, *removeAttr* por el método *prop*, válido para alterar propiedades del html u obtener su valor. Cuando quieras quitar la propiedad *disabled* de un elemento, simplemente quita la propiedad (string vacio).

Elemento de lista

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input:checkbox').on('click',function(){
          calcular();
           var enviar = $('#enviar');
           var str_total = $('#total').val();
           var total = parseFloat(str_total.substr(1));
          if (total <= 50) {
            enviar.prop('disabled', "true")
          } else {
            enviar.prop('disabled', "");
          }
    });

});

function calcular() {
  var tot = $('#total');
  tot.val(0);
  $('.mis-checkboxes,.mis-adicionales').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('mis-checkboxes')) {
      tot.val(($(this).is(':checked') ? parseFloat($(this).attr('tu-attr-precio')) : 0) + parseFloat(tot.val()));
    } else {
      tot.val(parseFloat(tot.val()) + (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseFloat($(this).val())));
    }
  });
  var totalParts = parseFloat(tot.val()).toFixed(2).split('.');
  tot.val('$' + totalParts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + '.' + (totalParts.length > 1 ? totalParts[1] : '00'));
}
if (true) {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<html>

 <head>

  <td>Productos: </td>
  <br>
  <br>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <table width="500" border="2">
    <ul>
      <tr>

        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" tu-attr-precio="35" id="Café" class="mis-checkboxes" name="checkbox[]" value="Café">
          <label for="Café">Café</label>
          <br></td>
        <td>35</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>


          <input type="checkbox" tu-attr-precio="29" id="Té" class="mis-checkboxes" name="checkbox[]" value="Te">
          <label for="Té">Té</label>
          <br></td>

        <td>29</td>
      </tr>



      <td>


        <input type="checkbox" tu-attr-precio="28" id="chocolate" class="mis-checkboxes" name="checkbox[]" value="chocolate">
        <label for="chocolate">chocolate</label>
        <br></td>

      <td>28</td>
      </tr>


      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" tu-attr-precio="10" id="choclo" class="mis-checkboxes" name="checkbox[]" value="choclo">

        <label for="choclo">choclo</label>

        <br></td>

      <td>10</td>


      <table>

      </table>
      <br>
      <label><strong>Total</strong><label>
<input type="text" id="total" placeholder="0.00"required>

<input type="submit"  id="enviar" value="Enviar" disabled>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @cooper, me sirvió mucho. Eres un ídolo